# What should I add to my python dictionary to generate a new line beneath certain keys when dumped to yaml?

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

The yaml dumper stacks keys on top of each other which makes it look cluttered. I would like to add a new line between a few of my keys to spread them apart.

```py
d = {'key': value, 'key': value, 'key': value}
yaml.dump(d, out)
```

I've tried adding '\n' to keys to give a new line before that key but this does not work.

```py
d = {'key': value, '\nkey': value, 'key': value}
```

Still gives 
key: value
key: value
key: value

```
Desired:

    key: value

    key: value
    key: value

    Actual:
    key: value
    key: value
    key: value
```

Comment: Please provide an actual complete program, because that is not the actual result that you get from either of the `d` instances. The first one only has one key-value pair after instantiation, and the second has only two. Your desired output is invalid YAML, as keys in a mapping have to be unique. And if you add a newline to a key (or value) you just get a key with a newline (i.e. a double quoted scalar in YAML).

Comment: Just a wild guess (hence not putting it as an answer) have you tried CRLF line breaks? \r\n

Comment: @pinkwaffles that would get you a mapping key with a newline and carriage return embedded (`"\r\nkey"`)

Comment: Why did you delete your post on getting flow-style? I spent 20+ minutes writing an answer and your question got deleted just before I posted. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a newline to a key `key`, you get a key with an embedded
newline and that gets dumped as a double quoted scalar with an
explicit [mapping key indicator
character](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2772075) (`?`):

```
? "\nkey"
```

that is certainly not what you want.

What you need to do is insert a comment (empty lines are handled by
the same mechanism as comments in `ruamel.yaml`), at the appropriate
position in the `dict` like data structure that `ruamel.yaml` uses to
preserve such comments on round-trip:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

d = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}

data = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap(d)
data.yaml_set_comment_before_after_key('key2', before='\n')

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
key1: value1

key2: value2
key3: value3
```

Comment: Yes! Is there a way for me to do this for keys that are nested? This assumes 'key2' is top layer.

Comment: Keys are not nested, dictionaries (or mappings) can be nested when a value again is a dictionary. The above doesn't assume `key2` is on the top layer, it assumes `key2` is a key on the dict like `data`. That `data`, in this example, is at the root of the data structure, but there is no assumption that it has to be there.